# Blank Content PDF is generated using laravel-snappy

Tags: laravel, laravel-snappy

Some times ago Laravel-snappy is working on Ubuntu server. but Now it's not working .It's working fine in local window system but on ubuntu server it's generate blank pdf. wkhtmltpdf and other extension already install on server. 
How can i debug this laravel-snappy PDF.

Here is screenshot: 
[image]

snappy.php

```
return array(


    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => '"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64"',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),


);
```

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

May you need to change snappy configuration.

```
return array(

    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => 'C://"Program Files"/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => 'C://"Program Files"/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
);
```

This works for me in windows server.